# Bind function in jQuery plugin function

Tags: javascript, jquery, bind, document-ready

I'm trying to implement an infinite scroll in a div with filtering option, as well, filtering should work when user stops typing in the box.

Html:

```
 <div class="span2" style="margin-top: 50px;">
    <input id="Search" class="input-mysize" />

    <div id="listNav" style="height: 370px; border: 1px solid; overflow: auto; margin-right: 20px; width: 90%;">
    </div>
</div>
```

JS in Html:

```
 $(function() {

     function onSuccess(row, container) {
        container.append('<div style="border:1px solid; cursor: hand; cursor: pointer;" >' +

                                '<table border="0">' +
                                    '<tr>' +
                                    '<td id="Location' + row.Id + '">'+
                                            '<b>Name: </b>' + row.Name + '</br >' + '<b>Address: </b>' + row.Address + '' +
                                    '</td>' +
                                    '<td onclick="locationDetails(' + row.Id + ')"> > </td>' + 
                                    '</tr>' +
                                '</table>' +
                         '</div>');

        var tdId = "Location" + row.Id;
        var element = $('#' + tdId);
        $(element).click(function() {
            google.maps.event.trigger(arrMarkers[row.Id], 'click');
        });
    };

    //...
    $('#listNav').empty();
    $('#listNav').jScroller("/Dashboard/GetClients", {
        numberOfRowsToRetrieve: 7,
        onSuccessCallback: onSuccess,
        onErrorCallback: function () {
            alert("error");
        }
    });

    //...

     $('#Search').keyup(function(){
        clearTimeout(typingTimer);
        if ($('#myInput').val) {
            typingTimer = setTimeout(doneTyping, doneTypingInterval);
        }
    });

    function doneTyping () {
        startInt = startInt + 5;
        $('#listNav').empty();
        $('#listNav').unbind();
        $('#listNav').jScroller("/Dashboard/GetClients", {
            numberOfRowsToRetrieve: 7,
            start : startInt,
            locationFilter: $('#Search').val(),
            onSuccessCallback: onSuccess,
            onErrorCallback: function () {
                alert("error");
            }
        });
    };
});
```

rest of JS (based on jScroller plug in):

```
(function ($) {
"use strict";
jQuery.fn.jScroller = function (store, parameters) {

    var defaults = {
        numberOfRowsToRetrieve: 10,
        locationFilter: '',
        onSuccessCallback: function (row, container) { },
        onErrorCallback: function (thrownError) { window.alert('An error occurred while trying to retrive data from store'); },
        onTimeOutCallback: function () { },
        timeOut: 3 * 1000,
        autoIncreaseTimeOut: 1000,
        retryOnTimeOut: false,
        loadingButtonText: 'Loading...',
        loadMoreButtonText: 'Load more',
        fullListText: 'There is no more items to show',
        extraParams: null
    };
    var options = jQuery.extend(defaults, parameters);
    var list = jQuery(this),
        end = false,
        loadingByScroll = true;

    var ajaxParameters;

    if (options.extraParams === null) {
        ajaxParameters = {
            start: 0,
            numberOfRowsToRetrieve: options.numberOfRowsToRetrieve,
            locationFilter: options.locationFilter
        };
    }
    else {
        ajaxParameters = {
            start: 0,
            numberOfRowsToRetrieve: options.numberOfRowsToRetrieve,
            locationFilter: option.locationFilter,
            extraParams: options.extraParams
        };
    }

    list.html('');

    function loadItems() {
        preLoad();
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: store,
            type: "POST",
            data: ajaxParameters,
            timeOut: options.timeOut,
            success: function (response) {
                list.find("#jscroll-loading").remove();
                if (response.Success === false) {
                    options.onErrorCallback(list, response.Message);
                    return;
                }
                for (var i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) {
                    if (end === false) {
                        options.onSuccessCallback(response.data[i], list);
                    }
                }
                if (loadingByScroll === false) {
                    if (end === false) {
                        list.append('<div><a class="jscroll-loadmore">' + options.loadMoreButtonText + '</a></div>');
                    }
                }

                ajaxParameters.start = ajaxParameters.start + options.numberOfRowsToRetrieve;

                if (ajaxParameters.start >= response.total) {
                    end = true;
                    list.find('#jscroll-fulllist').remove();
                    list.find(".jscroll-loadmore").parent("div").remove();
                }
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                if (thrownError === 'timeout') {
                    options.onTimeOutCallback();

                    if (options.retryOnTimeOut) {
                        options.timeOut = options.timeOut + (1 * options.autoIncreaseTimeOut);
                        loadItems();
                    }
                }
                else {
                    options.onErrorCallback(thrownError);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    function preLoad() {
        if (list.find("#jscroll-loading").length === 0) {
            list.find(".jscroll-loadmore").parent("div").remove();
            list.append('<a id="jscroll-loading">' + options.loadingButtonText + '</a>');
        }
    }

    //called when doneTyping is called and first time page loaded 
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        loadItems();
    });


    //called when user scrolls down in a div
    $('#listNav').bind('scroll', function () {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() + $(this).innerHeight() >= $(this)[0].scrollHeight) {
            loadItems();
        }
    });

};
})(jQuery);
```

It's mostly working, **but at some cases when user stops typing**, the

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    loadItems();
});
```

and

```
$('#listNav').bind('scroll', function () {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() + $(this).innerHeight() >= $(this)[0].scrollHeight) {
        loadItems();
    }
});
```

are both called **instead of just first one**, adding bad html to the div. Most cases only jQuery(document).ready is called, **which is what i need**.

As well why is jQuery(document).ready() is called every time the doneTyping() is called ? I though it should be called only the first time the page is loaded after DOM is ready.

Comment: weird. neither your first snippet nor your second have anything to do with the user typing. It is not possible for the exact same `jQuery(document).ready()` to be called more than once.

Comment: @Kevin B, function doneTyping () in fourth snippet.

Comment: I'm referring to the text in the beginning. You said both snippets are being called when the user stops typing. Neither of them should be getting called when the user stops typing.

Comment: `document.ready` won't fire again due to an input changing - something is calling it if it's running again.  Where is `onSuccess`?

Comment: with the edit the same issue is still there... Neither of the two snippets you are refering to have anything to do with the user typing... The user stopping typing should NOT cause the page to scroll or the dom ready callback to get called again.

Comment: @Kevin B, thank you, I restructured it. I know this question is probably very cryptic and pain to resolve, so I don't expect too much. Thanks.

Comment: @KevinB, exactly, but for some reason when doneTyping is executed, both instances of loadItems are called.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense. How are you coming to the conclusion that both are getting called from each of those locations in the code? The document.ready one is literally impossible to be called again unless you are including the code again.

Comment: @KevinB, I debugged the code and see both are called, as well ajax method called two times.

Comment: there is no other JavaScript working except jQuery library. Anything else I could paste here to make it easier ?

Comment: Can you post the function `onSuccess`?

Comment: Maybe, it would make more sense if you narrowed down your code to only what is relevant. We need doneTyping, and how doneTyping is called. I haven't gone through your code line by line, but just skimming over it, i don't see where doneTyping is being executed.

Comment: @KevinB, it all seems to be there.

Comment: I see it. And i still see NOTHING that could possibly cause those two snippets to be triggered when doneTyping is called. The scroll event maybe, but the document.ready should not be getting called. that simply isn't possible without a page reload or including the script again, neither of which should be happening given your code.

Comment: @KevinB, That ajax call should not trigger the jQuery(document).ready, correct ?

Comment: Correct, it should not. That callback is actually defined as a promise object. Once it has been resolved, it ***can't*** be resolved again.

Comment: @KevinB, I have to .bind instances, with unbind to prevent both at same time. Could I mess up something there ?

Comment: You could, but it still wouldn't cause `jQuery(document).ready` to be called again. btw, does jscroller have a destroy method? emptying the listnav might not be enough to clear the plugin data.

Comment: I see what's happening. you ARE including jQuery(document).ready multiple times, and initializing the jscroller again is what is causing your problem. Every time you initialize the jscroller, you are executing `jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    loadItems();
});` which will immediately execute loadItems because the DOM is already ready.

Comment: you can't use `$('#listNav').jScroller("/Dashboard/GetClients", {
            numberOfRowsToRetrieve: 7,
            start : startInt,
            locationFilter: $('#Search').val(),
            onSuccessCallback: onSuccess,
            onErrorCallback: function () {
                alert("error");
            }
        });`, though tbh i don't know what you should replace it with.

Comment: @KevinB, thank you, I will have a look at this now.

Answer (score -1):

I assume that your `JS` code in your `HTML` starts with a `$(document).ready({})`, so there would be no need to add `$(document).ready({})` inside your plugin. Just call `loadItems();` without the document ready event.

Comment: And that will have 0 effect on the code and really should not be a suggested answer for this question.

Comment: @Archer So you are saying that adding `$(document).ready...` inside an already initialized plugin is a good idea? :-/

Comment: @MarceloPascual No, your suggestion is a good practice, ***However***, it has nothing to do with the problem presented in this question and will not help solve it.